# Receiving a POST request from Instagram using Sinatra

Tags: ruby, api, callback, sinatra, instagram

I created a TAG subscription to Instagram's real time api and Instagram is suppose to send a POST request to my callback after a hashtag I have subscribed to gets updated.  I'm not sure how to go about in grabbing the POST request from Instagram.  When I go to my callback url, it is blank.

What is suppose to go into this route?

> post '/callback' do
>
> end

If I go to my URL callback, should I be seeing the POST data from Instagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram will likely post data to this endpoint when tags are updated. According to [this document](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) there will be a json body coming in here. To get it do `request.body` in your block. The documentation has an example of the json that is passed in. To try it out you could use `curl` on the command line or `postman` a chrome plugin that makes it easy to do post requests.

Your question indicates that you think you should get something back when calling this endpoint. This is not the case. You are receiving data from instagram on this endpoint. You probably want to do something with the data. Store it in a database, post it to twitter or send a mail. The code to do that should go in your post block.

Comment: Thank you froderik.  You're right, I completely misunderstood what I was trying to do.  Thanks for your help, it cleared it up.  I kept thinking that by going to the callback url, I'll expect to see some data.  What i didn't realize was that I was submitting a GET request and that's why it was coming up blank.  Greatly appreciate the help.